# MSBuild compile failed due to C2220 error

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, msbuild, compiler-warnings

Hi I was tend to build a solution which contains multiple projects using MSBuild in command prompt

But I got error C2220
: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated Driver

I have searched and the whole site and they says

In visual stuido
project -> Properties -> configuration properties -> C/C++ -> disable some options and it works

I open it with VS2017 but there was no such option exists

I just wanna compile it using MSBuild in command prompt by removing /WX compiler option.

Of course, I have read MSBuild option but didn`t find it so I am asking this

1. is there any command option in MSBuidling removing /WX compiler option?
2. if not, how to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In the project properties go to:

Configuration properties > C/C++ > General

Select the dropdown next to Treat Warnings As Errors and make a choice.

[image]

Comment: I should add in answer to your question #1. C++ projects does NOT have a way to pass in an option to msbuild.exe to toggle treating warnings as errors. But C# projects can do that very easily.